# Microsoft Graph API Password Reset Only Accepts Null password

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to reset another user's password through the Graph API (specifically graph.windows.net, though the same behavior occurs using graph.microsoft.com as well).

I believe all security is properly set up. The application registration has the Directory.ReadWrite.All permissions and the service principal is a Global Administrator. There are no errors regarding insufficient privileges, but whenever I try to provide a password inside the password profile I get an error.

PATCH request to

> https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/users/{userPrincipalName}?api-version=1.6

with the following body gives me a 204 response.

```
{ 
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": null,
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true 
    }
}
```

But the same request with a password of "P@ssword1" or any other valid password returns a 400 Bad Request with the message **"One or more properties contains invalid values."**

Anyone encountered anything like this? These are accounts being synced from local AD but the password reset has been turned on in Azure and you can manually reset the passwords in AAD. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a problem with how AD sync is set up in their environment. Apparently a federated domain syncing to Azure AD locks out the ability to reset passwords via the Graph API but the error messages don't tell you its a permissions issue.

It's outline here under unsupported operations, my problem was not understanding the full AD environment set-up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-writeback

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want update user's password through the Graph API.

According to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update#permissions), when we update the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

Based on my test, we can modify someone's password by using the following steps:

1. Grant the permission by following this document.
2. Check the password in the profile whether satisfy minimum requirements as specified by the passwordPolicies property.
3. Use the following request to update someone's password.

The Request URL:

`PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}`

And the request body:

`{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "P@assword1"
  }
}`

If successful, this request returns a 204 No Content response code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did miss that note, so I added the Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission but get the same responses back. I mostly find it strange that I get the appropriate 204 response ONLY if I make the password null.

Comment: Did you Check the password in the profile whether satisfy minimum requirements as specified by the `passwordPolicies`property. If so, you can try is in the Graph Explore, and check  whether it work.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong URL, `graph.windows.net` is the legacy Azure AD Graph API. The Microsoft Graph APIs are located at `graph.microsoft.com`. While these APIs are similar in function, they're calling paterns are very different.

As kikang mentioned, in order to change a user's password you need need to request the [`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#directory-permissions) scope. There are a few important cavetes with this scope:

1. This is a Delegated scope, so it can only be requested when using Authorization Code or Implicit OAuth flows. It cannot be used with Client Credentials.
2. Before a User can consent to `Director.AccessAsUser.All`, you must first obtain Admin Consent from an Admin on the user's AAD tenant/instance.

Once you have the proper scopes consented, you need to issue a `PATCH` to the [`/user`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update) resource.

Your call will look similar to this:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json

{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "A-Strong-Password"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried it on both URLs (the legacy one still works fine for what its worth they more or less operate the same way, one just has a slightly different body for password reset). Turns out its a limitation of the Graph API itself when dealing with a federated local domain syncing to Azure AD. The error messages you get back just aren't very helpful. I assume it exists because they want you  to use the built in SSPR functionality in O365.